# Accessing nth element of a list in list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to build a function which works on lists of lists. This function would take the 1rst element of each list inside the big list, put them into a list together, then do this for the 2nd element, etc. 
        Ex:

```
tr[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]    
=> [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]
```

It can work for any data type, but for now I am trying to make it work for Int

Here is what I have so far, just the data declaration and a case for empty input:

```
tr :: [[a]] -> [[a]]

tr [] = []
```

Any help is much appreciated, or even a pointer to a place with information. My idea is that it will use the ++ operator, and the x:xs manipulation of List elements. My problem is figuring out how to access the head of each list respectively, and not just the first list. I can get the 1 from the example using:     head $ head  [[1,2,3]].

Comment: So you're trying to transpose a list of lists?

Comment: It might be worthwhile looking at [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose), which does exactly what you want

Comment: @EliSadoff yes actually it is transposition, I did not see that it was! 
Thanks :)

Comment: No worries! [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is an awesome resource.

Comment: @EliSadoff have one more question if you do not mind me asking, do you know any big resources other than the 'learn you a haskell' book,that you might have come across?

Comment: I can recommend http://haskellbook.com/

Comment: @Demostroyer I agree with Mika'il. Haskell Programming from First Principles is a truly excellent resource. I strongly recommend it.

Comment: @Mika'il Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Comments answer your question. But, a more generic/abstract version would be one which works with any [`Foldable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html) data structure, not only lists. That can be done with nested right folds:

```
import Prelude hiding (foldr)  -- older version ghc
import Data.Foldable (foldr, Foldable)

tr :: (Foldable f, Foldable s) => f (s a) -> [[a]]
tr = takeWhile (not . null) . foldr (foldr go id) (repeat [])
  where go i f (x:xs) = (i:x): f xs
```

then:

```
\> tr [[10,11],[20],[],[30,31,32]] 
[[10,20,30],[11,31],[32]]

\> tr [Just 1, Nothing, Just 2]
[[1,2]]
```